# SPARQL query - all items

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I need the SPARQL query  for all items (e.g. eBay (Q58024)) (=result) which have the headquarter location in e.g. San Jose (Q16553) and e.g. the country USA (Q30) (both input).

I am completely new so I need an example to get a better understanding.

Thank you very much!

Comment: and you tried nothing so far? I mean, it's a simple SPARQL query with a triple pattern (resp. two).

Comment: I don't know how it helps you to get a query in a language that you do not understand, but here, all items with headquarter in San Jose: `select * {?s wdt:P159 wd:Q16553}` - with country in USA: `select * {?s wdt:P159 wd:Q16553 ; wdt:P17 wd:Q30}`

Comment: To be honest, any RDF and SPARQL tutorial would help you better than the queries here ...

Comment: @AKSW I tried it a little bit but at the moment I don't get. But this examples helps very much. Thank you for your help!